# TypeScript path mapping "Cannot find module a-mapped/a"

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I have a project with the following structure:

```js
┌ tsconfig.json
│ {
│   "compilerOptions": {
│     "baseUrl": ".",
│     "paths": { "a-mapped/*": ["a/*"] }
│   }
│ }
│
├ a
│ └─ a.ts
│    export const a = 1;
└ b
  └─ b.ts
     import { a } from "a-mapped/a";
     export const b = a + 1;
```

When I run `tsc`, the resulting `b.js` contains:

```js
var a_1 = require("a-mapped/a");
exports.b = a_1.a + 1;
```

If I try to run it with `node`, I get the error "Cannot find module `a-mapped/a`".

I expected `tsc` to generate an import from `../a/a`, not `a-mapped/a`. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this problem myself not too long ago. Interestingly enough, typescript will understand path mappings, but keep them as-is in the compiled javascript *[by design](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9910#issuecomment-234729007)*.

> The compiler does not rewrite module names. module names are considered resource identifiers, and are mapped to the output as they appear in the source
>
> The module names you write are not going to change in the output. the "paths" and "baseURL" are there to tell the compiler where they are going to be at runtime.
> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9910#issuecomment-234729007

There are several ways to deal with this.

### ts-node

You can use ts-node instead of node to run your project.

**Pros**:

- easy to use, no-hassle.

**Cons**:

- you might not be able to do this, for example if you're writing browser code, a library, or don't control the runtime environment.
- Performance *might* be an issue, especially startup times.

### transformers

Alternatively you can use [typescript transformers](https://dev.doctorevidence.com/how-to-write-a-typescript-transform-plugin-fc5308fdd943) to make the compiler output correct javascript files (for example [@zerollup/ts-transform-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zerollup/ts-transform-paths?activeTab=readme) and [ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript)).

**Pros**:

- Faster compilation times, you can use `ttsc --watch` reliably.

> Note: I have tested this setup and its much faster than using any tools when using `--watch`.

**Cons**:

- At least for now, you need to use a typescript wrapper like ttypescript.
- Somewhat harder to set-up.

### tools

Finally, you can use a tool that would fix the paths for you in your generated javascript ([ts-module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@momothepug/tsmodule-alias), [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias), [ef-tspm](https://github.com/ef-carbon/tspm)).

**Pros**:

- use unadulterated typescript.
- Easy to set-up (just run the tool after compiling!)

**Cons**:

- might lead to slower compile times.
- watch operation is harder to set-up.

I ended up using ef-tspm to fix the files, and it generally works, although I'm not fully satisfied with the build times, and it's probably worth exploring transformers and ttypescript. In case it helps, I have created a [typescript / node project with path aliases set-up](https://github.com/lucascaro/ts-node-starter).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, you answered my [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795349/how-to-configure-typescript-project-references-for-absolute-imports-of-composite) . One question, at this point: if TS Path Mapping doesn't do what we naturally expected it to do, what good is it for and what's the intended usage? I'm reading [its documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) and I remain puzzled: when would you use it if there is no rewriting done by TSC?!

Comment: sad that ef-tspm doesnt work with esnext modules.