# typescript version 3.6.2 paths @ not working for nodejs server: Cannot find module '@/database/models/User'"

Tags: node.js, typescript

> error: "Cannot find module '@/database/models/User'"

Building a nodejs server with typescript, where the tsconfig is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "paths": {
      "@constants": [
        "src/constants"
      ],
      "@database": [
        "src/database"
      ],
      "@domains": [
        "src/domains"
      ],
      "@http": [
        "src/http"
      ],
      "@services": [
        "src/services"
      ],
      "@utils": [
        "src/utils"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not completely sure why, but the output js for one of the files retains the @ in the require:

> var User_1 = tslib_1.__importDefault(require("@/database/models/User"));

But, and quite rightly so, node cannot find this module :/

Is there a config I am missing to get the output to be mapped to the correct path?

In this case it would be:

> var User_1 = tslib_1.__importDefault(require("../database/models/User"));

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014619/typescript-path-mapping-cannot-find-module-a-mapped-a

Comment: the above answer has the answer in the github repo demo posted using ttsc