# How to configure TypeScript Project References for absolute imports of composite sub-project to not crash at runtime?

Tags: typescript

Here's a clonable project containing minimal code for my question: [GitHub / ronjouch / demo-ts-project-references](https://github.com/ronjouch/demo-ts-project-references).

In this project, I'm setting up a [TS Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html)-based project so that sub-project `app` depends on composite sub-project `lib`.

With this setup, inside `app/index.js`, I am able to

```
import { LETTER_A } from '../lib';
```

And with this setup, great news,

1. `npm run compile` (which calls `tsc -b lib app`) builds successfully.
2. `npm start` (which calls `node dist/app/index.js`) runs successfully.

Now, I noticed (thanks to VSCode) that TSC was also happy if I was importing from `lib` using a [***non-relative import***](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html):

```
import { LETTER_A } from 'lib';
//          no "../" here ^
```

, which I prefer and WANT because, in a real application, it's super extra convenient to do such an import from a deeply-nested file as opposed to

```
import { LETTER_A } from '../../../../lib';
//     AAaaaAaAAaaargh :( ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, although TSServer is happy and TSC successfully compiles with the following great `tsc --traceResolution` output...

```
======== Resolving module 'lib' from '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj/app/index.ts'. ========
Explicitly specified module resolution kind: 'NodeJs'.
'baseUrl' option is set to '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj', using this value to resolve non-relative module name 'lib'.
Resolving module name 'lib' relative to base url '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj' - '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj/lib'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj/lib', target file type 'TypeScript'.
File '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj/lib.ts' does not exist.
File '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj/lib.tsx' does not exist.
File '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj/lib.d.ts' does not exist.
File '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj/lib/package.json' does not exist.
File '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj/lib/index.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
======== Module name 'lib' was successfully resolved to '/home/ronjouch/demo-ts-proj/lib/index.ts'. ========
```

... things don't go well at runtime, and I my program crashes with a `Error: Cannot find module 'lib'`, which is reasonable because the generated JS is:

```js
const lib_1 = require("lib");
```

, which is obviously bogus given the folder structure (where `app` and `lib` are siblings folders at the same level)! At this point, I would have expected TS to have transformed my non-relative import into a relative one!

- I tried fiddling with [Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `baseUrl`, `rootDir`, `rootDirs`, `paths`, without success: the generated JS is still faulty, and still crashes.
- I tried in particular to set up a [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) (e.g. `"paths": { "/*": [ "*" ] }` plus replacing my `'lib'` import with `'/lib'`, which would be fine too), without success: similarly, the `/` isn't handled and ends up in the produced JS, which expectedly crashes. Is it possible to use both a path mapping and project references?

→ Is there a way to tell TSC to transform my non-relative into a relative one? Or am I mis-using the feature and, in that case, why are tsc + tsserver happy about them at check/compile time? If I am mis-using, what would be the correct way to reach what I want (project references + absolute imports avoiding `../../../../lib` hell)?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer to my question: my problem is not about Project References, it's about the [Path Mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) feature, and my question is the same as [TypeScript path mapping "Cannot find module a-mapped/a"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014619/typescript-path-mapping-cannot-find-module-a-mapped-a) : I'm expecting a kind of code modification/generation from TSC that TSC does *not* do by design.

Quoting mhegazy from closed [TypeScript issue #9910 - Path mapping should relative path ?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9910#issuecomment-234729007),

> The compiler does not rewrite module names. module names are considered resource identifiers, and are mapped to the output as they appear in the source
>
> The module names you write are not going to change in the output. the "paths" and "baseURL" are there to tell the compiler where they are going to be at runtime.

[TypeScript path mapping "Cannot find module a-mapped/a"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014619/typescript-path-mapping-cannot-find-module-a-mapped-a) then offers solutions, none of which I like, so I think I'm back to `../../../..` relative imports .