# ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND during runtime of my typescript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I'm working on a simple typescript project and can't get through the module resolution/paths problem.
Among the pages I already went through are:
[Modules guides from TS website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/theory.html) and other SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014619/typescript-path-mapping-cannot-find-module-a-mapped-a).

I just can't wrap my head around the zoo of different module types, targets, module resolutions, paths and references and need a bit of help.

I have two packages

```
┌ tahacana-lib
│ └─ src
│     └─ tahacana-lib.ts
│ └─ tsconfig.json
│ └─ package.json
│
│
└ tahacana-server
  └─ src
      └─ tahacana-server.ts
  └─ tsconfig.json
│ └─ package.json
```

## Library

The library export classes like `export class TahacanaPlayer {...}`

tsconfig in the library:

```
{   "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "NodeNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": { "*": [ "node_modules/*" ] }
    },
    "include": [ "src/**/*" ]
}
```

## Server

The server imports classes from the library like this:

```
import { TahacanaPlayer } from 'tahacana-lib/tahacana-lib.js'
```

tsconfig in the server:

```
{   "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ES2022", 
        "lib": ["ES2022", "DOM"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es2022",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [ "node_modules/*" ],
            "tahacana-lib/*": ["../tahacana-lib/src/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": [ "src/**/*" ],
    "references": [
        { "path": "../tahacana-lib"}
    ] }
```

I compile project by

```
> cd tahacana-server
> tsc -b
```

Compilation happens without any issues. Both packages are compiles and JS, d.ts and maps files are generated.

After that I attempt to run by

```
> node ./dist/tahacana-server.js
```

My node version: 20.10.0
tsc version: 5.3.3

Getting this error while trying to run the app: `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'tahacana-lib' imported from /Users/acha/dev/projects/tahacana/tahacana-server/dist/tahacana-server.js`

I did have a version that does not use "paths" for the library. Just using relative path in the import like `import { TahacanaPlayer } from '../../tahacana-lib/src/tahacana-lib.js'` but had same module not found in the runtime.

Tried different combinations of tsconfig parameter with no result. Appreciate some ideas and explanation.